# Client Credentials Flow with Certificate Authentication - What is the best approach for secure use of the certificate stored on the client?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, dynamics-crm-online

Microsoft Graph API and Dynamics Web Services both support [certificate authentication with client credentials flow](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service).

Are there any security concerns in "Authenticated Users" having read access to the private key of the authentication certificate stored on the IIS server? The private key is not exportable.

Are there any security concerns in using the same certificate for both SSL of the IIS site and the client credentials flow authentication?

Comment: If you use IIS server to issue a certificate, you could find the private key file in the local.

Comment: The certificate is in the Personal folder of the Local Machine certificate store.